# RMI with IP - ClassNotFoundException, UnmarshalException, ServerException

Tags: ip, rmi, classnotfoundexception

there anyone who can help me with establishing rmi server using ip. I've been searching it for few days on the net, but cannot solve my problem.

Client

```
public static void main(String[] agrcs) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException, MalformedURLException {
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {     System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "F:\\škola\\pg2\\LodeSemestralka\\java.policy");

        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    }
    String ip = agrcs[0];
    Integer port = new Integer(agrcs[1]);

        server = (ShipServer) Naming.lookup("//"+ip+":"+port+"/"+SERVER_NAME);
}
```

Server

```
static public void main(String[] agrcs) throws RemoteException {
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "F:\\škola\\pg2\\LodeSemestralka\\java.policy");
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    }

    String ip = agrcs[0];
    Integer port = new Integer(agrcs[1]);

    playground = new Playground();
    try {
        Naming.bind("//" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + SERVER_NAME, playground);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        playground = null;
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When servers is called, it throws

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lode.gameCore.Playground
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:413)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.bind(Naming.java:128)
    at server.Server.main(Server.java:38)
    at lode.game.StartUpScreen.createNewGame(StartUpScreen.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.noProxyActionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:662)
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.actionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:698)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at ....
```

and in lode.gameCore is `public interface ShipServer extends Remote {...}` and `public class Playground implements ShipServer, Serializable {...}`

I was using LocaleRegistry and it works perfectly but only on one PC. I need the application running on more PC using RMI with IP via the net, to communicate etc.

And in java.policy is `grant {permission java.security.AllPermission;};`

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lode.gameCore.Playground(Unknown Source)
    ...
    at java.rmi.Naming.bind(Naming.java:128)
```

The RMI Registry doesn't have that class in its CLASSPATH. The Registry needs the remote interface, the stub if any, and any application classes they depend on, and so on until closure.